# Show SharePoint document library / List in provider hosted addin

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint-online, provider-hosted

I want to show a specific folder from a SharePoint document library in my App. I would like to show them, with all SharePoint functionalities (like open in Word, delete, checkout etc.)
 I would like to do that similar to MS Teams - there's the e.g. the general folder shown inside of teams. (And in my eyes it is not a frame)

My Question: 
Is there any framework (Javascript or c#) or code sample to do this, like in teams?

I know, how to rebuild it with e.g. a gridview and CSOM.

A link to the library/folder does not help, then the user leave the app context.